# Iterate over an array's elements to perform queries using Laravel Eloquent advanced WHERE clauses

Tags: mysql, laravel-5, eloquent

I have an **array** (`arr`) with *n* elements, *n* = 1 or 2, and a **table** in database called `employees` that contains two fields (`name` and `surname`)

I want to perform the following query using ***Eloquent*** (and, possibly, some kind of *iteration* ?), in order to implement an "instant search" functionality:

```
select * from employees
where (name LIKE '%arr[0]%' AND surname LIKE '%arr[1]%')
OR
where (name LIKE '%arr[1]%' AND surname LIKE '%arr[0]%')
```

**EDIT:** To state my question more clearly, in case there is ***only one element*** in the `arr` I would like to perform the following query:

```
select * from employees
where (name LIKE '%arr[0]%' AND surname LIKE '%arr[0]%')
```

that is, to look for the given `arr` element in either `name` or `surname` fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use [Advanced Where Clauses](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queries#advanced-where-clauses) which allow you to group `WHERE`s (like you'd do with parenthesis):

```php
$arr = ['Some', 'Name'];
$employees = Employee::where(function($query) use ($arr) {
                 $query->where('name', 'LIKE', '%' . $arr[0] . '%')
                       ->where('surname', 'LIKE', '%' . $arr[1] . '%');
             })->orWhere(function($query) use ($arr) {
                 $query->where('name', 'LIKE', '%' . $arr[1] . '%')
                       ->where('surname', 'LIKE', '%' . $arr[0] . '%');
             })->get();
```

Which produces the query:

```
select * from `employees` where (`name` LIKE ? and `surname` LIKE ?) or (`name` LIKE ? and `surname` LIKE ?)
```

The `?` will be passed in as parameters to the prepared statement by laravel.

Comment: thank you for your answer, however this solution works great given that the `arr` contains exactly two elements, but in case there is only one element (or possible more than two in a future version) you get an "undefined offset" ErrorException

Comment: You're right, if it's only one, you can easily use another query which has only two `WHERE`s, not 4, but when it gets more than 2 values that'd be a lot of query-building if you want to check for every possible combination.

Comment: this sounds like a good idea, but is it possible to implement this if/else statement using some kind of fancy "eloquent technique". Because, since i eager load the Employee model, using a conditional statement and a second query would result in duplicate code in the controller

Comment: I don't think so. MySQL/Eloquent is not meant to execute this kind of logic. You ask for something, you get something. But deciding on _what_ to ask isn't Eloquent's job.